# QuickTime component causing errors when running osascript command

Tags: applescript, security, mojave

If I run a simple osascript from the command line:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to activate'
```

I get hundreds of this error:

`2019-01-19 13:07:31.224 osascript[3908:9313907] Error loading /Library/QuickTime/EyeTV MPEG Support.component/Contents/MacOS/EyeTV MPEG Support:  dlopen(/Library/QuickTime/EyeTV MPEG Support.component/Contents/MacOS/EyeTV MPEG Support, 0x0106): code signature in (/Library/QuickTime/EyeTV MPEG Support.component/Contents/MacOS/EyeTV MPEG Support) not valid for use in process: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not`

I have to wait for the errors to finish running before the script actually runs, which is annoying.

I tried using codesign to fix the issue:

`codesign --architecture x86_64 -f -s "My Cert" 'EyeTV MPEG Support'`

But it didn't help. I believe the error is caused by Mojave's security policy.

One way to fix this is to remove the the QuickTime component from this folder. But I'm hoping there is a better fix as the EyeTV app requires this component to run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I move it out into a new folder I created called ~/BadLibraries.
EyeTV still Works for me.

Comment: Wow, you are right! Maybe eyetv was just being hinky when I first tried it.

Comment: actually, it's just re-installing the component when I open EyeTV.